# Aries JPA EntityManager services not starting for WebLogic data source

Tags: jpa, osgi, weblogic, weblogic12c, aries

I'm trying to get an OSGi persistence bundle working on WebLogic's built-in Felix framework. As per [the WebLogic OSGi documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/osgi.htm#WLPRG753), my WebLogic data source `test-ds` appears to be available as a service within OSGi:

```
Service 59 - [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RemoteDataSource, javax.sql.DataSource, javax.sql.CommonDataSource, java.sql.Wrapper, weblogic.jdbc.extensions.WLDataSource, java.rmi.Remote, weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceMetaData, weblogic.common.resourcepool.ObjectLifeCycle, weblogic.jndi.CrossPartitionAware] (pid: n/a)
  from Bundle 0 - System Bundle (org.apache.felix.framework), version 5.6.0
    Name: test-ds
    service.bundleid: 0
    service.scope: singleton
```

I've created a persistence bundle `com.test.persistence-bundle` with the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

... and persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="test-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/test-ds</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>osgi:service/test-ds</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>test.model.TestEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

... and manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1556912147017
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_171
Built-By: roadkill
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: test-persistence-bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.test.persistence-bundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
DynamicImport-Package: org.hibernate.proxy,javassist.util.proxy
Export-Package: test.model;uses:="javax.persistence";version="1.0.0"
Import-Package: javax.persistence;version="[2.2,3)",org.hibernate.proxy;
 resolution:=optional,javassist.util.proxy;resolution:=optional
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Provide-Capability: osgi.service;effective:=active;objectClass="javax.pe
 rsistence.EntityManager";osgi.unit.name=test-pu,osgi.service;effective:
 =active;objectClass="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory";osgi.unit.
 name=test-pu,osgi.service;effective:=active;objectClass="org.apache.ari
 es.jpa.template.JpaTemplate";osgi.unit.name=test-pu,osgi.service;effect
 ive:=active;objectClass="org.apache.aries.jpa.supplier.EmSupplier";osgi
 .unit.name=test-pu
Require-Capability: osgi.extender;osgi.extender="aries.jpa",osgi.service
 ;effective:=active;objectClass="javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvid
 er";javax.persistence.provider="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceP
 rovider",osgi.service;effective:=active;objectClass="javax.transaction.
 TransactionManager",osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-4.2.0.201903051501
```

I've also created a client bundle `com.test.service-impl` which implements `TestService` from another bundle:

```
@Component(service = TestService.class)
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-pu")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(em);
    }
}
```

The `EntityManager` instance should be injected via the blueprint for the service implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v2.0.0" xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <jpa:enable />
    <tx:enable />

    <bean id="testService" class="test.service.impl.TestServiceImpl"/>
    <service ref="testService" interface="test.service.TestService"/>
</blueprint>
```

However, `em` is always null. It seems the EntityManager services are never started even though all bundles are Active. I get the following message when updating `com.test.service-impl`:

```
13:20:36.380 [Blueprint Extender: 1] INFO org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl - Blueprint bundle com.test.service-impl/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT is waiting for dependencies [(&(osgi.unit.name=test-pu)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager))]
13:20:36.380 [Blueprint Extender: 1] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher - Sending blueprint container event BlueprintEvent[type=GRACE_PERIOD, dependencies=[(&(osgi.unit.name=test-pu)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager))]] for bundle com.test.service-impl/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
```

I'm using Aries JPA to wire everything together with Hibernate as the persistence provider. I also have Aries Blueprint and Aries Transaction installed along with all required dependencies.

Here are the relevant bundles from my bundlelist:

```
com.test.persistence-api (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT) "test-persistence-api" [active, 23] 
com.test.persistence-bundle (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT) "test-persistence-bundle" [active, 25] 
com.test.service-impl (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT) "test-service-impl" [active, 21] 
javax.persistence-api (2.2) "Java(TM) Persistence API jar" [active, 45] 
javax.transaction-api (1.2) "javax.transaction API" [active, 10] 
javax.transaction-api (1.3) "javax.transaction API" [active, 18] 
org.apache.aries.blueprint.annotation.impl (1.0.1) "Apache Aries Blueprint Annotation Impl" [active, 32] 
org.apache.aries.blueprint.core (1.10.2) "Apache Aries Blueprint Core" [active, 19] 
org.apache.aries.jpa.api (2.7.2) "Apache Aries JPA Container API" [active, 44] 
org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint (2.7.2) "Apache Aries JPA blueprint" [active, 22] 
org.apache.aries.jpa.container (2.7.2) "Apache Aries JPA container" [active, 64] 
org.apache.aries.jpa.javax.persistence_2.1 (2.7.2) "Apache Aries JPA Specification 2.1 API" [active, 67] 
org.apache.aries.jpa.support (2.7.2) "Apache Aries JPA support" [active, 66] 
org.apache.aries.proxy (1.1.4) "Apache Aries Proxy Service" [active, 70] 
org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint (2.2.0) "Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint" [active, 52] 
org.apache.aries.transaction.manager (1.3.3) "Apache Aries Transaction Manager" [active, 34] 
org.apache.aries.util (1.1.3) "Apache Aries Util" [active, 30] 
org.hibernate.common.hibernate-commons-annotations (5.1.0.Final) "hibernate-commons-annotations" [active, 56] 
org.hibernate.orm.core (5.3.10.Final) "hibernate-core" [active, 31] 
org.hibernate.orm.core (5.4.2.Final) "hibernate-core" [active, 29] 
org.hibernate.orm.osgi (5.4.2.Final) "hibernate-osgi" [active, 59] 
org.osgi.service.blueprint (1.0.2.201505202024) "org.osgi:org.osgi.service.blueprint" [active, 27] 
org.osgi.service.cm (1.5.0.201505202024) "org.osgi:org.osgi.service.cm" [active, 6] 
org.osgi.service.coordinator (1.0.2.201505202024) "org.osgi:org.osgi.service.coordinator" [active, 73] 
org.osgi.service.jdbc (1.0.0.201505202023) "org.osgi:org.osgi.service.jdbc" [active, 37] 
org.osgi.util.function (1.1.0.201802012106) "org.osgi:org.osgi.util.function" [active, 65] 
org.osgi.util.promise (1.1.1.201810101357) "org.osgi:org.osgi.util.promise" [active, 17]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It turns out this was due to a bug in the version of Felix that WebLogic ships with. I was able to upgrade the framework by simply replacing `\wlserver\server\lib\org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar` and `\wlserver\server\lib\osgi.jar` with the latest versions of [felix-main](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.main) and [osgi-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.core), respectively.

---

While trying to figure out the source of the issue, I ended up downloading and manually reading through Karaf's `jpa`, `transaction`, and `hibernate` features to ensure all of the proper bundles were installed and started in the correct order. [WebLogic allows you to specify start levels by placing bundles inside of subdirectories within the `osgi-lib` folder](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/osgi.htm#WLPRG778). I'm not sure how helpful this was in the long run, but it gave me some confidence that things were set up in a verified way.

Here's the list of bundles, with versions and start levels, that I gathered from the Karaf features (not shown: logging/console/shell stuff):

```
START LEVEL 100
   ID   State         Level  Name
[   0] [Active     ] [    0] System Bundle (6.0.3)
[   1] [Active     ] [   10] Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.9.14)
[   2] [Active     ] [   11] Apache Felix File Install (3.6.4)
[   3] [Active     ] [   20] org.objectweb.asm (7.1.0)
[   4] [Active     ] [   20] org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis (7.1.0)
[   5] [Active     ] [   20] org.objectweb.asm.commons (7.1.0)
[   6] [Active     ] [   20] org.objectweb.asm.tree (7.1.0)
[   7] [Active     ] [   20] org.objectweb.asm.util (7.1.0)
[   8] [Active     ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint API (1.0.1)
[   9] [Active     ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint CM (1.3.1)
[  10] [Active     ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint Core (1.10.2)
[  11] [Resolved   ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint Core Compatiblity Fragment Bundle (1.0.0)
[  12] [Active     ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy Service (1.1.4)
[  13] [Active     ] [   20] Apache Aries Util (1.1.3)
[  14] [Active     ] [   30] jaxb-api (2.3.1)
[  15] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX API (1.1.5)
[  16] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint API (1.2.0)
[  17] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint Core (1.2.0)
[  18] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Core (1.1.8)
[  19] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries Whiteboard support for JMX DynamicMBean services (1.2.0)
[  20] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JPA Container API (2.7.2)
[  21] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JPA blueprint (2.7.2)
[  22] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JPA container (2.7.2)
[  23] [Active     ] [   30] Apache Aries JPA support (2.7.2)
[  24] [Active     ] [   30] Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Activation API 1.4 (2.9.0)
[  25] [Active     ] [    5] Apache Felix EventAdmin (1.5.0)
[  26] [Active     ] [    5] Apache Felix Metatype Service (1.2.2)
[  27] [Active     ] [    8] jansi (1.17.1)
[  31] [Active     ] [   80] Byte Buddy (without dependencies) (1.9.10)
[  32] [Active     ] [   80] CDI APIs (1.2.0)
[  33] [Active     ] [   80] ClassMate (1.3.4)
[  34] [Active     ] [   80] org_dom4j_dom4j_2.1.1_dom4j-2.1.1.jar (0)
[  36] [Active     ] [   80] geronimo-jta_1.1_spec (1.1.1)
[  37] [Active     ] [   80] hibernate-commons-annotations (5.1.0.Final)
[  38] [Active     ] [   80] hibernate-core (5.4.2.Final)
[  39] [Active     ] [   80] hibernate-osgi (5.4.2.Final)
[  40] [Active     ] [   80] Java Annotation Indexer (2.0.5.Final)
[  41] [Active     ] [   80] Javassist (3.24.0.GA)
[  42] [Active     ] [   80] Expression Language 3.0 API (3.0.0)
[  43] [Active     ] [   80] javax.interceptor API (1.2)
[  44] [Active     ] [   80] Java(TM) Persistence API jar (2.2)
[  45] [Active     ] [   80] Apache Aries JPA Specification 2.1 API (2.7.2)
[  46] [Active     ] [   80] javax.transaction API (1.2)
[  47] [Active     ] [   80] JBoss Logging 3 (3.3.2.Final)
[  48] [Active     ] [   80] Java Transaction API (1.1.1.Final)
[  49] [Active     ] [   80] Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint (1.1.1)
[  50] [Active     ] [   80] Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint (2.2.0)
[  51] [Active     ] [   80] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: javax.inject (1.0.0.2)
[  52] [Active     ] [   80] org.osgi:org.osgi.service.jdbc (1.0.0.201505202023)
[  53] [Active     ] [   80] pax-transx-tm-api (0.4.3)
[  54] [Active     ] [   80] pax-transx-tm-geronimo (0.4.3)
[  55] [Active     ] [    9] Apache Felix Coordinator Service (1.0.2)
[  61] [Active     ] [    1] Apache Felix Declarative Services (2.1.16)
[  65] [Active     ] [    1] org.osgi:org.osgi.util.function (1.1.0.201802012106)
[  66] [Active     ] [    1] org.osgi:org.osgi.util.promise (1.1.1.201810101357)
```

I also made some changes to the OSGi framework configuration itself via the WebLogic console:

- **Boot delegation** - these were mostly copied from the Karaf configuration, although `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` are definitely needed to avoid `ClassNotFoundException`s from bytebuddy:

```
com.sun.*, javax.transaction, javax.transaction.*, javax.xml.crypto, javax.xml.crypto.*, jdk.nashorn.*, sun.*, jdk.internal.reflect, jdk.internal.reflect.*
```

- **Init Properties** - again, mostly copied from Karaf:

```
felix.startlevel.bundle=80
org.apache.aries.blueprint.synchronous=true
org.apache.aries.proxy.weaving.disabled=org.objectweb.asm.*,org.slf4j.*,org.apache.log4j.*,javax.*,org.apache.xerces.*
org.apache.aries.proxy.weaving.enabled=none
org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning=100
```

Lastly, it appears WebLogic sets the `name` property of the published DataSource service to the JNDI name of the data source itself. Thus, the full value for `jta-data-source` should be something like:

```
osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(name=test-ds)
```

Hope this helps.